# How can I open password protected Word documents on my iPad for free?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

I would like to open a password protected Word document on my iPad. I've found paid solutions but nothing for free. Am I missing an option?

Answer (score 2):

Try [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) which is very inexpensive ($0.99) and most useful app on iPad. I use it all the time both on iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The free [GMail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail-email-from-google/id422689480?mt=8) app can open password protected .docx attachments.

Answer (score -1):

This video saved me...100% working method to unlock a word document
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxhEFJPAv9w

Comment: Could you summarise the video here? That way, your answer will still be useful even if the video is deleted from Youtube (and, of course, there are people who can't access Youtube as their corporate firewall blocks Youtube).

Comment: The question wasn't how to hack a password, it was how to legitimately read a locked document.